# Google Map Integration

Tags: google-maps

I want to create a Interactive google map as per http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/map.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E93932 .. I just wanna ask if I can do that using wordpress plugin, or can I have that kind of fucntionality even without using wordpress plugin? but how?..
here are the details..

any tip please.. do I have to do to manually or there is an easy way for me  to be able to do that.. please help me :)

Comment: Please try to edit your Q, as you got some misspellings. Thanks :) Also: Please provide more details. Are you trying to display Custom Post type data on the map, or where's the data for the map comming? What **exactly** are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you want here...

You want something like yelp on the right? ( [here](http://www.yelp.com/c/atlanta/restaurants) )

That will update the website when you change your map boundaries?

Edit: I think you should look at [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/store-locator-le/) . Is it this?

Comment: Thanks for recommendations, but the entries will be coming from a form, the users will submit their entries and I will collect all the address and display it on map, I think the store locator is not the solution, unless it will allow me to add an address from the my form.. (the form is formidable pro)

Comment: @markyeoj I asked you to update your question with the details. You now provide them (partly) in _a comment_ to an answer, that's not answer, but an extended list of Questions and guessing...

Comment: here are the details..
I am creating a B&B website that offers free, featured, and premium listings. All the listing will be coming form a single form which is created using Formidable Pro http://formidablepro.com/ , and users must become a member to use the free listing and upgrade it to featured and premium. of course all entries has a location address included, and I want those addresses to be marked on my google map dynamically. My address field are 

Adress 1 - txtfield
City / State - txtfield
Country  - txtfield

Comment: i can display entries using the shortcode of each field using the custom display of formidable pro just like here in there demo  http://demo.formidablepro.com/real-estate-listings/, please view the code on how they displayed.

 any tip please.. do I have to do to manually or there is an easy way for me  to be able to do that.. please help me :)